# MySQL fixed-length and variable-length data types

Tags: mysql, types

I am optimizing DB and there is something which is not clear to me about fixed-length data types.

As far as I know these data types are **fixed-length**:

- CHAR(n)
- DATE
- TIME
- DATETIME
- TINYINT
- SMALLINT
- MEDIUMINT
- INT
- FLOAT
- DOUBLE

And these are **variable-length**:

- TEXT
- VARCHAR
- BLOB

**Please correct me if I am wrong!**

Now, my question is: **Are these data types fixed-length or variable-length?**

- **TIMESTAMP**
- **ENUM**

Thanks.

Comment: this... is a very broad question

Comment: Updated for better understanding my questions. Actually I just want to know if what I know about fixed-length data types is correct or not? And TIMESTAMP, ENUM are fixed-length or variable-length data types? (2 questions in total)

Comment: Timestamps and enums are fixed-length types.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are not correct on some datatypes.

**DATETIME/TIMESTAMP**

`TIMESTAMP` and `DATETIME` are similar, however TIMESTAMP uses only half the storage space when compared to `DATETIME`. There are however notable disadvantages to using `TIMESTAMP` so you should check the official docs to see which one you need. But most of the the `DATETIME` would be the better choice.

You don't have to worry about fix/variable lengths for this datatype

**NUMBERS**

You are able to store integer by setting a length i.e `int(20)` but in terms of storage it has no difference and hence has no meaning.

`TINYINT SMALL INT MEDIUMINT BIGINT`

These datatypes require 8, 16, 24, 32, and 64 bits of storage space respectively. Each of them has different maximum and minimum values. If you are sure your values will not exceed a certain number, you should choose the smallest int datatype to conserve space and improve performance. You should consult the official docs for more information on the figures.

`FLOAT` and `DOUBLE` are approximate calculations and you don't have to specify a precision. Setting a precision and inserting a value beyond the specification, your value will be rounded to the specification. Again see the official docs for this.

**VARCHAR**

`VARCHAR`, as you expect is variable-length, but keep in mind, don't specify something like `VARCHAR(100)` when you only need 5 characters, because although the length is variable when stored on disk, it takes the length you specify when working with RAM, so you will be wasting precious memory.

**BLOB and TEXT**

`BLOB` and `TEXT` are stored in a specially way, depending on the storage engine you use. They are usually stored in an "external" area. You should avoid using this unless if the string is **VERY** long. This datatype cannot index the full length and also is not supported by the Memory and so is not used by the system's memory. When calling for it a temp table will be created on disk with the MyISAM storage engine and this would cause a huge performance degradation.

**ENUM**

This is very compact and you set specific values to a field when you create a table. The strings are fixed and changing an `ENUM` column requires an `ALTER TABLE`, so you won't have to worry about fix/variable lengths for this one.

**EDIT:**

I found a page in the official docs that answers all your questions [Data Type Storage Requirements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/storage-requirements.html)

Comment: It's not clear where I am wrong. I have read official documents to understand what you are talking about (same as in official document) but they are not the straight-forward answers for my questions. In case you are misunderstanding me, **fixed-lenth** refers to **static** and **variable-length** refers to **dynamic**. Thank you anyway!

Comment: If you mean in terms of fixed storage space, then yes, you are *mostly* correct. `FLOAT` stores values as 4 bytes if it has 0 to 24 digits and 8 bytes if 25 to 53 digits. Also the `TIME DATE DATETIME TIMESTAMP` all have take up a fixed amount of storage space. And keep in mind the BLOB and TEXT disadvantages.

Comment: added a link that can help you

Comment: @bash- The link you provided answers the question about enums too: _1 or 2 bytes, depending on the number of enumeration values (65,535 values maximum)_.